# sklearn.model_selection module not found

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying linear regression from a data but when I try the following:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

it gives me this error:

```
line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
KeyError: 32
```

sklearn, numpy and scipy are all installed but then also I am not able to use `sklearn.model_selection` and `linear_model`.

How can I solve this problem? I have already tried upgrading every module.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can tell us the sklearn verison by doing `import sklearn; sklearn.__version__`

Comment: most likely you've a version <= 0.19. If not, make sure that you have installed the package in the correct environment (e.g. if you're using virtual eng)

Answer (score 3):

What version of  `sklearn` are you using?

In versions 0.19 and prior, the function `train_test_split()` was located in [`sklearn.cross_validation`](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html#sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split).
To use it:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

From version 0.20 onwards it can be found in [`sklearn.model_selection`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)
To use it:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Does that help?

Comment: No thats not correct. `model_selection` came into version 18. See changelog here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.18.html#version-0-18. So that means, `cross_validation` was officially in version 17 and before. It was also into version 18 and 19 as a deprecated package. [Check this](https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/classes.html#recently-deprecated).

Comment: @VivekKumar Ok, I should be more precise: in versions 0.18 and 0.19 the function `train_test_split()` can be found in both (although it has a deprecation warning in one of them), but since 0.20 in can be found only in `model_selection` and in 0.17 and earlier it can be found only in `cross_validation`.